# Test running null and letters?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I would like to automatically test run NULL as the variables and also letters, however I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int inuti(double x, double y, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    int x_inuti;
    int y_inuti;

    if (x1 < x2)
        x_inuti = x > x1 && x < x2;
    else
        x_inuti = x > x2 && x < x1;
    if (y1 < y2)
        y_inuti = y > y1 && y < y2;
    else
        y_inuti = y > y2 && y < y1;
    return x_inuti && y_inuti;
}

int main(void) {
    double x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2;
    char text_y, text_x1, text_y1, text_x2, text_y2;
    char text_x;
    int resultat;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {

    text_x = "lalala";
    text_y = "lala";
    text_x1 = "text";
    text_y1 = "";
    text_x2 = "";
    text_y2 = "";


        printf("punktens x-varde: %.1f \n", text_x);


        printf("punktens y-varde: %.1f \n", text_y);

        printf("\n");

        printf("Ena hornets x-varde: %.1f \n", text_x1);


        printf("Ena hornets y-varde: %.1f \n", text_y1);

        printf("\n");

        printf("Andra hornets x-varde %.1f \n", text_x2);


        printf("Andra hornets y-varde %.1f \n", text_y2);

        printf("\n");

        resultat = inuti(text_x, text_y, text_x1, text_y1, text_x2, text_y2);


        if (resultat == 1)
            printf("Punkten var inuti rektangeln.\n");
        else if (resultat == 0)
            printf("Punkten var utanfor rektangeln.\n");

        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    //Here I'm testing all number variables - This works fine
    for (x = -10; x <= 10; x++) {
            for (y = -10; y <= 10; y++) {
                for (x1 =-10; x1 <= 10; x1++) {
                    for (y1 = -10; y1 <= 10; y1++) {
                        for (x2 = -10; x2 <= 10; x2++) {
                            for (y2 =-10; y2 <= 10; y2++){

                                printf("punktens x-varde: %.1f \n", x);


                                printf("punktens y-varde: %.1f \n", y);

                                printf("\n");

                                printf("Ena hornets x-varde: %.1f \n", x1);


                                printf("Ena hornets y-varde: %.1f \n", y1);

                                printf("\n");

                                printf("Andra hornets x-varde %.1f \n", x2);


                                printf("Andra hornets y-varde %.1f \n", y2);

                                printf("\n");

                                resultat = inuti(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2);


                                if (resultat == 1)
                                    printf("Punkten var inuti rektangeln.\n");
                                else
                                    printf("Punkten var utanfor rektangeln.\n");

                                printf("\n");
                                printf("\n");


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I guess the problem with test running letters is that the type is char instead of double. I even tried without a value ( "" ) but it still doesn't test run. It only test runs the numbers

Comment: C types are not nullable. Are you trying to store `NULL` in all of your data types? That won't work. Also, a `char` data type can only hold one number, between 0 and 255. That is large enough for an ASCII character, but you can’t store a string in it. Could you clarify what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @yellowantphil I working on test running inputs but it has to be automatic. I test runns different values automatically. I have no problem test running all combinations of numbers but I don't know how to test run letters and (if a value is empty) null. I tried so many different ways but I can't figure it out

Comment: Use `%f` only when printing type `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Looping over `chars`

The `char` type, although generally used for storing characters, is implemented as a small integer. It can have different min and max values. You can `#include <limits.h>` and then use the macros `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` to find the values. These are equal to 0 and 255 on most computers.

You can test all possible values of a `char` this way:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
```

...

```
char text_x;
int i;
for (i = CHAR_MIN; i <= CHAR_MAX; i++) {
    text_x = (char) i;
    // test something with text_x here
    // not all possible values are printable characters
    // isprint will return true if the character is printable
    if (isprint(text_x)) {
        putchar(text_x);
    }
}
```

I looped over `int i` rather than `char text_x`, because `i` can go higher than `CHAR_MAX`. Once it does, you exit the loop. Looping over `text_x` in this way will just cause its value to wrap back to zero, and you’d have an infinite loop.

Or you can loop over specific characters this way:

```
#include <string.h>
```

...

```
char text_x;
char my_favorite_characters[] = "abcdefgABCDEFG0123456789.+-";
int i, imax;
imax = strlen(my_favorite_characters);
for (i = 0; i < imax; i++) {
    text_x = my_favorite_characters[i];
    printf("%c is one of my favorite characters\n", text_x);
}
```

### Why store numbers in a `char`?

Characters in C are just stored as numbers, so if you have this line:

```
char mychar = 'a';
```

Then it looks like you’re storing an `a`, but the compiler just takes the numeric value of `a` and stores that in `mychar`. Nearly everyone uses ASCII, where `'a' == 97`. So when using ASCII, this line is equivalent to the one above, although more cryptic:

```
char mychar = 97;
```

Some numbers will not correspond to printable characters, or may not be characters at all, depending on your character encoding.

### Trying to store anything else in a `char`

Variables in C are never “empty.” Any numeric type, including `char`, cannot have a NULL value. If you don’t set a value for your variables, they will either equal zero, or they will be undefined, depending on how you declared the variable. Pointers can be `NULL`, which is the same as setting your pointer to zero.

Your line `text_x = "lalala";` will not work, because `text_x` has room for only one character. `"lalala"` returns a pointer to an array of `char`s. The compiler should complain about being asked to cast a pointer into a `char`. This is also true of `text_x = ""`: the compiler returns a pointer to an empty string and tries to store it in `text_x`, which won’t work.

Comment: Is that char text_x a letter or number?

Comment: `text_x` is just a variable of type `char`. That’s all the compiler knows. You would generally store characters in it, but you can just as well input numbers directly. I’ll expand the answer a bit.

Comment: Thank for explaining so beautifully. As I mentioned before, I can already test run numbers. What I want to be doing is to test run letters. I want to change the variables to something that can store letters. I though that `char` only stored letters but I've learned now that it converts them to numbers. Is there any type that can store letters?

Comment: @John Not really. All the computer can store is numbers, and that’s true of any programming language. C just makes the mapping of letters to numbers (`'a' == 97`) somewhat more obvious than some other languages do. If you want to test only specific characters, that isn’t hard to do either. I’ll add it to my answer, since an example is only a couple lines of code.

Comment: @John OK, that took more than two lines. Just loop over the chars in an array, the way I added in the answer. Then you don’t have to worry about the numeric values of the characters.

Comment: Thank you very much @yellowantphil! I really appreciate the work that you have done. It's working now.

Comment: @John Glad I could help, and glad you got it working!